# ([javaScript)Access camera through HTML5 browser in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, html5-video

I would like to develop a web app for mobile and need to access iphone camera from the web browser without native mobile app.

I don't want to take a picture and upload one from my album.

Can I capture video-cam using iphone?
If I can not do this, please give me any suitable suggestions to do this.
Thanks for any help

Comment: @yuriy636 - The browser compatibility table there says this isn't possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access iPhone or Android camera using HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345973/how-can-i-access-iphone-or-android-camera-using-html5)

Comment: According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream) the answer at the duplicate hasn't changed much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607067/can-you-access-the-iphone-camera-from-mobile-safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a file input and then parse the file they upload: `<input type="file" accept="image/*">`. On iOS, you get the option to take a picture.